# How to verify if Erlang runtime and loader is indeed running native code

Tags: erlang, erl, hipe

I am trying to explore performance improvements by switching to native compilation for my Erlang code (native option and `{hipe, [verbose]}`).

How can I make sure that the Erlang loader is indeed using the native code from the beam file?

Is there some verbose logging option for the loader to know what it is up to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [code:is_module_native/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#is_module_native-1):

```
1> code:is_module_native(lists).
false
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. However my module which I compiled as native is reported to be running as non-native (false for the above call). I am certain HIPE compiled it as I can see HIPE compile time messages and the size of the beam file is significantly large as compare to non-native compilation. Can you gimme some pointers where to look for ?